# Set the name of DataTable after it's set

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I set 4 datatables as members of my class like this:

```
With retval
    .LookupData = ConvertArrayToDatatable(engines, ConversionType.Normal)
    .AdditionalData1 = ConvertArrayToDatatable(drivetrains, ConversionType.Normal)    
    .AdditionalData2 = ConvertArrayToDatatable(transmissions, ConversionType.Normal)
    .AdditionalData3 = ConvertArrayToDatatable(options, ConversionType.Options)
End With
```

How do I go back and set the names of those DataTables so when someone references the members of those class they can pick them depending on their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [DataTable.TableName property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename.aspx) for each of them:

```
dt.TableName = "Name"
retval.LookupData.TableName = "LookupData"
```